# I want a sample that uses Deep Link to navigate to a specific Flutter page

Tags: android, flutter, deep-linking

I want to go from a web page to a specific page in the Flutter app.
I don't know how to do it, so I want complete source code.

Rewritten AndroidManifest.xml.
I accessed myapp: // mypage from Chrome, but I couldn't open the app.

```xml
<meta-data android:name="io.flutter.app.android.SplashScreenUntilFirstFrame" android:value="true" />
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LEANBACK_LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>

            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
                <data android:scheme="mypage" android:host="myapp" />
            </intent-filter>
```

I want to go to Flutter's PageA from the link on the web page.
---flow---
Click link on web page
 Open App 
Display ListPage of apps made with Flutter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

maybe you need to take a look at this article

https://medium.com/@muratcanbur/intro-to-deep-linking-on-android-1b9fe9e38abd